# Moving .png getting out of the screen

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm relatively new to the pygame scripting world and I needed help on writing a game : it will be a labyrinth with a player moving from a starting point to an arrival point.

I decided to start with the basics by making a window where the character ( a .png file ) moves when the numpad keys are pressed.

The problem is, when my .png reaches the screen it moves through.
How can I prevent it from getting out of the screen ? ( PS : I want, if possible, a solution where I don't have to use a class, I absolutely hate those and I'm not comfortable at all with them )

Here's the code of what I've written so far :

## importation librairies / importating libraries

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

F1=pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), RESIZABLE) # création fenêtre / creating main window

bg=pygame.image.load("background.jpg").convert() # chargement et conversion de l'image / loading and converting picture
F1.blit(bg, (0,0)) #collage de l'image de fond / sticking background
pygame.display.flip() # raffraichissement écran / refreshing screen

perso=pygame.image.load("perso.png").convert_alpha()
F1.blit(perso, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

F1_rect=F1.get_rect()
position=perso.get_rect()
F1.blit(perso, position)

pygame.display.set_caption("Deadalus V 0.0.0.1")

continuer = 1 # création d'une boucle infinie / creating main loop

pygame.key.set_repeat(1,1)
while continuer:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                continuer = 0
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_KP2:
                    position = position.move(0,3)
                if event.key == K_KP5:
                    position = position.move(0,-3)
                if event.key == K_KP1:
                    position = position.move(-3,0)
                if event.key == K_KP3:
                    position = position.move(3,0)
        F1.blit(bg, (0,0))
        F1.blit(perso, position)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You will need some condition that checks the representation of the player's location and the bounds of your playing area.  I think sooner or later you are going to need classes to help with abstraction (unless, *maybe*, you are a functional programming guru.) Classes will be handy to learn -- you'll need to be comfortable with them eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know where I can find a good complete tutorial on how to uses class ?

Comment: This is pretty much the standard tutorial, although I'm sure a Google search will give you more: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to look it up when I have the time.

Comment: Python is a good language to learn classes/objects, as everything in Python is an object. Integers are objects, booleans are objects, even functions are objects, the only difference is that you write your own classes and the others are built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [clamp](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp)

```
position.clamp_ip(F1_rect)
```

That way your position rectangle will be allways inside F1_rect.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! ( Although I think I'll be back with some other questions ;)